# Execute Equation in Map Algebra

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I am in the process of shifting my raster calculations over from manually entering them into Raster Calculator to executing them in a Python script. I am curious if I can execute equations such as the following in Map Algebra, which is Python friendly:

`.00001 * Power("RasterLayer1",2) - 0.0145 * "RasterLayer1" + 79.16`

For some background, there will always be one raster layer that I want to perform computations with in the script, as opposed to numerous.

Comment: Did you see this? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/map-algebra/building-complex-statements.htm

Answer (score 1):

See [What is Map Algebra](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/map-algebra/what-is-map-algebra.htm) and [Working with Raster Objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/map-algebra/working-with-raster-objects.htm) in addition to the link in Kirk's comment. For example:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
inraster = Raster("rasterlayer or path to raster")
outraster = .00001 * Power(inraster ,2) - 0.0145 * inraster  + 79.16
outraster.save("path to output raster")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had a suspicion it would lead somewhere along these lines!